# PowerBI Slicers filtering other slicers

Tags: powerbi, data-warehouse

Fairly new to PowerBI and Datawarehouse, but a lot of SQL experience

Trying to figure out why some of my slicers interact and others don't (I've enable filter in interactions).

So i have manufacturing data and I have departments and operators, my visualizations all filter correctly, but slicers not. When I select a dept I want the operators slicer to filter. I added the deptcode to the operators dimension and there is a relationship, but id doesn't filter (same issue with depts and configs, and I was going to add to deptcode to configs to make that work, but it seems I'm missing something)

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

[image: Slicers]

[image: Model]

Answer (score 1):

There is no active relationship where filters on `DimDepartments` can flow to `DimOperators`. Notice that the relationship you do have is inactive (hence the dotted line).

You might be able to get what you're looking for if you make the relationship from `DimOperators` to `FactSFDEvents` bi-directional so that filters can propagate through the fact table back to `DimOperators`.